# Parametric Equations of a surface

Tags: geometry

I need to find the Parametric Equations of the following surface. But I dont know the method. Can someone help me please. $$\frac {x^2}{a^2}+\frac {y^2}{b^2}-\frac {z^2}{c^2}=1$$ $$\frac {x^2}{p}+\frac {y^2}{q}=2z$$ $$\frac {x^2}{a^2}+\frac {y^2}{b^2}-\frac {z^2}{c^2}=0$$

Comment: Just a note: The word _the_ (as in "the parametric equations") signifies uniqueness when there is none. It's preferable to say "a set of parametric equations" or something of that type. (Separately, depending on your intended purposes, hyperbolic trig functions may be "nicer" than square roots.)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In each of these problems, the horizontal cross sections are ellipses. This is to say, when you let $z=v$, you get an equation of the form (after rewriting it)
$$\frac{x^2}{\alpha(v)^2}+\frac{y^2}{\beta(v)^2}=1$$
Then the parametric equation is given by
$$x = \alpha(v)\cos(u), y = \beta(v)\sin(u), z=v$$
For example, for the first problem, you get $\alpha(v) = a\sqrt{1+\frac{v^2}{c^2}}, \beta(v) = b\sqrt{1+\frac{v^2}{c^2}}$.

Comment: So according to you method $\alpha(v)$ and $\beta(v)$ for second are $\sqrt{2pv} \space and \space \sqrt{2qv}$ respectively. Right?

Comment: @florence The common feature of all these surfaces is that they are **surfaces of revolution** with the general form that can be found for example in formulas (9)(10)(11) of (http://mathworld.wolfram.com/SurfaceofRevolution.html).